# Why is the code for my next button looping the slideshow but the previous button isnt?

Tags: javascript, button, slideshow

I successfully coded buttons for an auto-advancing slideshow. Both buttons work but only the next button is able to loop through all images. When I reach the beginning with the previous button the whole function breaks and the errors say, that it can't find inactive or active elements.

What am I missing?

```js
document.getElementById('next1').onclick = function() { 

 var lon = items.length;
 items[ptr].className= "inactive";

 if(ptr==lon-1){
  ptr=0;
 }
 ptr++;

 items[ptr].className = "active";
}

document.getElementById('previous1').onclick = function() {

 var lon = items.length;
 var p = ptr-1;

 items[ptr].className= "inactive";
  if(ptr==lon){
  ptr=items.length;
 }
 ptr--;
 items[ptr].className = "active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It's:

```js
document.getElementById('next1').onclick = function() { 
 var lon = items.length;
 //alert(lon);
 items[ptr].className= "inactive";
 if(ptr==lon-1){
  ptr=0;
 }
 ptr++;
 items[ptr].className = "active";
}
document.getElementById('previous1').onclick = function() { 
 var lon = items.length;
 var p = (ptr-1);
 if(p<0){
  p += items.length;
 }
 
 items[ptr].className= "inactive";
 if(ptr==p){
  ptr=items.length;
 }
 ptr = p;
 
 items[ptr].className = "active";
}
```